# How to use filtered audio in complex filter in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the `highpass` audio filter then trying to use `showfreqs` on the resulting audio stream but it's not working. The `showfreqs` filter uses the original audio stream instead of the filtered one.

Command:

`ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex highpass,showfreqs,format=yuv420p highpass.mp4`

I tried naming the `highpass` output but it didn't make any difference:

`ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex highpass[hi],[hi]showfreqs,format=yuv420p highpass.mp4`

How do I structure my command so `showfreqs` uses the output from `highpass`?

**UPDATE**

I'm using FFMPEG 4.1.4 installed on Mac via Homebrew.

Source audio: https://dsc.cloud/weavermedia/audio.mp3

Commands and resulting files:

Run `highpass` on audio.mp3:

- `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex highpass highpass.mp3`
- result: https://dsc.cloud/weavermedia/highpass.mp3 CORRECT

Run `showfreqs` on audio.mp3:

- `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex showfreqs,format=yuv420p showfreqs.mp4`
- result: https://dsc.cloud/weavermedia/showfreqs.mp4 CORRECT

Run `showfreqs` on highpass.mp3:

- `ffmpeg -i highpass.mp3 -filter_complex showfreqs,format=yuv420p showfreqs.mp4`
- result: https://dsc.cloud/weavermedia/highpass-showfreqs.mp4 CORRECT

Run `highpass` and `showfreqs` in series on audio.mp3:

- `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex highpass,showfreqs,format=yuv420p highpass.mp4`
- result: https://dsc.cloud/weavermedia/highpass.mp4 INCORRECT

I tried several different source audio files and always get the same results.

I tried on 2 different Macs, albeit both with FFMPEG 4.1.4 installed via Homebrew.

I tried with different highpass settings and get same results (the default highpass settings are enough to hear the difference anyway).

**UPDATE 2**

Looking at the resulting videos side by side in QuickTime I see that `showfreqs` does actually appear to be using the audio stream from `highpass` but the final video contains the original unfiltered audio.

So my problem is actually how to get the resulting video to use the filtered audio stream instead of the original.

Comment: Your original command should work, and indeed does work here. Try with a different audio or aggressive settings in highpass.

Comment: @Gyan Updated the post with commands and links to resulting audio and video files. Can you confirm the command works with my source file?

Comment: @Gyan Updated again, seems that `showfreqs` is actually using the `highpass` audio stream but the resulting video is using the original. Is that expected? How do I get the filtered audio into the resulting video file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showfreqs` converts its audio input to a video output, so ffmpeg will fallback on the original audio for audio output. In order to avoid this, split the highpass result and pass one copy to showfreqs while leaving the other for audio output.

```
ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex highpass,asplit=2[sf][aud];[sf]showfreqs,format=yuv420p;[aud]anull highpass.mp4
```

Comment: On Mac I had to enclose the whole filter string in quotes, I think because of the semicolons, but after that it worked perfectly. Thanks.